# Recursive Permutation (counting rule)

Tags: java

I looked through a bunch of questions and I didn't find this. I need to write a recursive method that returns a Permutation, P(N,K). Meaning, pool of 20 objects, draw 3, how many possibilities are there for the order you draw them in? The answer is 20*19*18.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public double perm(long N, long K)

{
   if (K == 1)
      return N;
   else
      return perm((N*(N-1)), (K-1));
}
```

N is the pool, K is how many pulls. My problem is figuring out how to make the "N*(N-1)*(N-2)..." bit work. Say I do this:

`perm(10,3)`

After my first time through the code I've got, N would be 10*9, or 90, which means that on the second loop, it'd be calculating 90*89, not (10*9)*8. I can't figure out how this is supposed to work, but the professor assigned it so it must be possible.

I could do this really easily with a FOR lop, but it can't be a for loop.
I don't really want the solution, just some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Second `return` should be `return N * perm(N - 1, K - 1);`, so `perm(18, 1)` returns `18`, `perm(19, 2)` returns `19 * 18`, and `perm(20, 3)` returns `20 * 19 * 18`.

Comment: First of all, name your variables with lower case character. Second, please remind me is it called permutations or variations (my best recall would be - variations(n, k)

Comment: @zlakad I think you're referring to [permutation *vs* combination](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html), and the correct word is "permutation" (without repetition).

Comment: @Andreas, you see, I've studied mathematical statistics and probabilities long time ago, and I cannot recall PERMUTATIONS vs. VARIATIONS! B/c I know very well what would be combinations..

Comment: @zlakad According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation#Mathematics): *Variations without repetition, an archaic term in combinatorics still commonly used by non-English authors for k-permutations of n.* ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. That was the solution. It took me a couple minutes to figure out why it worked, but once I did it seems obvious.

Comment: @Andreas, so, I am archaic dinosaur, hahah -- 30 years ago I learned what are the combinations (with or without repetition) what would be permutation of set (size n) and what are variations... I assume there are some lexical inconsistencies. Never mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursing (is that a word?) with the multiplication result.

`return perm((N*(N-1)), (K-1));`

Here, N*(N-1) = 90 (N being 10 initially), hence the result `perm(90), k-1)`

You should multiply the result of P(N-1, K-1) with N like :

`N * P(N-1,  K-1)`